# Proof of a limit theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove the following theorem. Let $I$ be an open interval that contains the point $c$ and suppose that $f$ is a function that is defined on $I$ except possibly at the point $c$. If $m \le f(x) \le M$ for all $x$ in $I \setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$, then $m \le L \le M$.

Really not sure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we will prove only the first inequality: $m \le L$.  The other follows from a symmetric argument.

Suppose by way of contradiction that $L < m$.  This means there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $L + \epsilon < m$.  By the definition of a limit we know there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $|x-c| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

We can write the inequality as $$-\epsilon < f(x) - L < \epsilon.$$  Which gives $$f(x) < L + \epsilon < m.$$ However this is a violation of our hypothesis.  Therefore $m \le L$ as desired.